# Python json find dictionary in list by specific key value

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I was using api to get information about bus lines and got a list of dictionaries of the information.

Below are examples.

```
list = [{'start':'location A',
 'end':'location B',
 'routeNo':'1'},
{'start':'location C',
 'end':'location D',
 'routeNo':'2'},
{'start':'location E',
 'end':'location F',
 'routeNo':'3'}]
```

I am trying to get the whole dictionary of specific route by its 'routeNo'. For example I want to use '3'  to get information of this route. Expected result is below.

```
{'start':'location E',
 'end':'location F',
 'routeNo':'3'}
```

The closest thing I have tried is

```
print(list[2])
```

It's no ideal because I am not searching it, I am just getting the third item in list.

So I am looking for other ways to get the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could search it:

```
def find_route(data, route_no):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.get('rounteNo') == route_no, data))

route = find_rounte(route_list, '3')
```

Note i renamed `list` to `route_list`. That is because `list` is a built-in function and you've overwritten, which is a bad practice.

Also, assuming you are a beginner, here is a simpler to understand version:

```
def find_route(data, route_no):
    return [route for route in data if route.get('rounteNo') == route_no]
```